# How do I repair my damaged truck?

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

I can see from the main menu -> diagnostics screen that my truck is damaged, and how much it will cost to repair, but there is no option to repair it or advice on how to do so.

How do I repair my truck?

[image: diagnostics screen]

Answer (score 8):

Just like in real life, you can't fix your vehicle with the press of a magic button. You have to get the vehicle to a service center. Each city usually has one, as indicated by a red square with a wrench symbol.

[image: service center]

If you don't wish to drive to one, you can, alternatively, press <kbd>F7</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to be towed straight to the nearest service center. You will be charged for the towing though as opposed to driving yourself to one. So it comes down to fuel costs and real-world time vs towing costs.

[image: emergency recovery screen]

When parked at a service center, you will see the following:

[image: at a service center]

And you will then be given the option of what to repair, with a repair button at the bottom:

[image: repair option available]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot repair a damaged trailer though.

... unless you edit a saved `game.sii` file - then you can 'repair' each item (engine, chassis, trailer, etc.) 
Any damage will be listed as '`wear`' ... edit lines that start with
`wear: &`  (followed by an 8 character hex number, beginning with `3`) to read ...

```
wear: 0
```

If you've 100% damaged anything it will read

```
wear: 1
```